# Python - Function calling problems

Tags: python, function

I just started learning python 2 days ago and Im trying to make some kind of text based adventure to practice , the only problem Im having is with functions:

```
def menu_op():
    print('1- Action 1')
    print('2- Action 2')
    choice= input('Choose action: ')
    return choice

def action_op(x):
    if x == 1:
        print('You chose action 1')
    if x == 2:
        print('You chose action 2')

menu_op()
action_op(menu_op())
```

The idea behind this is to call the menu function , which gives a value equal to user's input , which gets fed into the action function when the latter is called and does something depending on the user choice.

Cant tell what im doing wrong though , as the code doesnt seem to work. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: *"doesnt [sic] seem to work"* is not a helpful problem description. Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)? Why do you call `menu_op` twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using Python 3.x.  In that version, [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string object like `raw_input` did in Python 2.x.  This means that the return value of the function `menu_op` will always be a string.

Because of this, you need to compare `x` with strings rather than integers:

```
if x == '1':
    print('You chose action 1')
elif x == '2':
    print('You chose action 2')
```

I also changed the second `if` to `elif` since `x` could never equal both `'1'` and `'2'`.

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer thank you very much , I would have swore raw_input was used to return a string !! Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: `raw_input` does not exist in Python 3.

Comment: @Trenloco if you're used to Python 2.x, and you're now working in Python 3.x, you should absolutely take a look at the list of changes. Python 3.x is not backwards compatible by design. https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `menu_op()` function twice. The first time it gets called choice is not passed to `action_op()`

```
menu_op()      #return is not catched
action_op(menu_op())
```

And the value returned from `menu_op` is a string so you should compare strings in `action_op` instead of comparing `x` with integers

```
def action_op(x):
    if x == 1:
           ^^^  #should compare strings here ->  x == "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

`choice= int(input('Choose action: '))  # make choice an int to compare`

```
In [1]: 1 == "1"
Out[1]: False

In [2]: 1 == int("1")
Out[2]: True
```

`input` is a string and you are comparing `if x == 1` where `x` is `"1"`